# How many outcomes are there?

Tags: probability, distributions, sampling

[image]

I am not sure how many outcomes there would be. In this case would I use multiplication rule (16 outcomes), permutation(12 outcomes) or combination (6 outcomes)?

Comment: Have you considered simply enumerating all possible samples in each case?  That is likely to be more instructive than guessing at a formula to apply.

Comment: Does order matter? For your purposes, is choice (529, 664) different from (664, 529)? Why or why not?